# Ignore calling of __unicode(self) in django

Tags: python, django, unicode, self

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    AnalysisID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    AnalysisName = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.AnalysisName
```

I want to use `Analysis.AnalysisID` in my template, but the row objects return `Analysis.AnalysisName` instead of `Analysis.AnalysisID` when I reference `Analysis.AnalysisID`.

P.S.: I dont want to remove `Analysis.__unicode__()` as it is needed in admin.

Comment: No, that doesn't happen. Please show the view and template.

Comment: What do you mean by *return AnalysisName instead of AnalysisID when i call Analysisobject.AnalysisID*? Can you show us the code you are using when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need define method `__unicode__` inside you model class, like this:

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
     AnalysisID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     AnalysisName = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.AnalysisName
```

Comment: I think that might have been a copy-paste error on the asker's part.

Comment: @user3078733 Does your code have ``__unicode__()`` defined inside of ``Analysis`` or outside?